# Traefik - HTTPS Certificats renew delay

Tags: traefik

We've setup Traefik with Docker to enjoy automatic https certificates obtention & renewal.

By looking into Traefik docs we found no reference to a possible way of specifying when to renew certificates (every 30 days for instance, or 30 days before expiration ...).

- When does Traefik choose to renew certificates by default?
- Is there a way to specify a time range to Traefik for it to renew certificates, for instance 30 days before expiration?

Comment: The issue seems having already been noticed here by the way: https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/1083

Answer (score 0):

Traefik renews certificates that expire in the next 30 days. This is not configurable as of the time of writing.